# Windows 8, Python 2.7 and lxml in a virtualenv

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, virtualenv, lxml, arcgis

I'm using python 2.7.3  It is the prepackaged version that comes with ArcGIS.  In order to contaminate my ArcGIS Python I'm trying to set up a virtual environment to use for non ArcGIS development.  This worked well and there's an excellent tutorial here:

http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/

on setting up virtualenv using powershell.

A specific library I do want to install in the virtual environment is lxml and trying to use pip to install it in my virtual environment throws the error:

unable to find vcvarsall.bat

I realise this is a pretty common error but I have the added complexity of using the ArcGIS packaged version of Python.  So far of the available fixes aare working as they are either for Windows 7, or Windows 8 but Python 3.3.

So far I've installed MS Visual C++ 2008 but windows couldn't find the vcvarsall.bat in multiple searches.  I've also tried downloading libxml2 but am unsure where to place it to avoid conflict with ArcGIS and is what I'm trying to do even possible with the ArcGIS distributed version of Python?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I worked it out.  It remains to be seen what happens regarding ArcGIS but so far it's coping.

First up I removed the reference in windows Environments> Paths to the C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x

I then downloaded the latest version of Python 2.7.x nd installed it to C:\Python276

I changed the Environments>Paths to C:\Python276 and C:\Python276\Scripts

Next up I set up a virtual environment for development using [this](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/) excellent guide.

lxml still wasn't working but I found [this](http://webdevon.com/install-lxml-in-a-simple-and-quick-way-on-windows/) which was the only solution for lxml I've found that works.

To get around the problem of ArcGIS and pathways etc I returned the paths to C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x and removed the reference to C:\Python276

As I don't want to be installing / updating / messing around with ArcGIS's Python install I then changed the Powershell profile file (see the end of the [first tutorial](http://www.tylerbutler.com/2012/05/how-to-install-python-pip-and-virtualenv-on-windows-with-powershell/)).  To change powershell's path to "C:\Python276;C:\Python276\Scripts;" I added the following to the profile file:

```
$ENV:PATH = $ENV:PATH -replace "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.2;$" , "C:\\Python276;C:\\Python276\\Scripts"
```

This temporarily changes the Python path when in a Powershell session but when it ends ArcGIS can run as usual.